# How do I set the line width in OpenGL relative to the viewing area of a frame buffer?

Tags: opengl, object, buffer, frame, primitive

glLineWidth rasterises the width so it shows as that width on the screen. I want it to be that width on a frame buffer.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean when your render the line in an offscreen context?

Comment: Yes but it seems to suddenly work now. I'm hoping it stays like that.

I think the problem was something else. I doesn't matter as long as it appears to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your screen width is a different size from your frame buffer?

```
desired_size = size_on_screen * (frame_buffer_width / screen_width)
```

Comment: So, there is no simple way?

Well I'm using frame buffer objects and I want to render lines to these. Since the lines should be at any angle I guess trigonometry will be needed. It might just be easier to do a filled polygon generated with trigonometry.

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Simple way to what? Please give us more hints. "the lines should be at any angle" is just to vague. FYI glLineWidth command works with FBOs.

Comment: glLineWidth works but it changes the width to the screen width.

If I change the size of the screen and the game scales the lines wont scale with it as an example.

I've almost got the polygon solution working.

Comment: I just need polygon anti-aliasing but I can't get that to work.

glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH) doesn't work.